# What's the default value of an union in avro Idl?

Tags: json, apache, avro, idl

For unions in avro Idl something like below what would be the default values?
 1. union {null, string} var = null;
 2. union {string, null} = "xyz";
 3. union {null, string} = "xyz";
 4. union {null, string, array} = [];

My assumption is the default values would be always the first item in the union. Is my understand correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay, I found the answer (from the [apache user guide](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Unions])).
The default type of an *union* will be always it's first value. So, here the default types for the above examples would be *NULL*, *STRING*, *NULL* and *NULL*. And the default values would be the ones those assigned to the union.

So, in the above unions only the first and second *unions* are syntactically correct and I think all other (3 and 4) unions are syntactically wrong because defaultValues assigned to them doesn't match the *union's* defaultType.

Answer (score 0):

In second union (union {string, null} = "xyz") is missing name of field type of union. Is missing some name of union before "=". For example: union {string, null} myString = "xyz"